# Double Quotes in NSURL request

Tags: xcode, null, couchdb, nsurl, double-quotes

Apache CouchDB requires the key to be enclosed by double quotes: ", however when escaped the resulting nsurl returns (null) when being logged to the console and the resulting response (null) as well, obviously.

Here's the code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://username:password@gcg.cloudant.com:5984/points/_design/user/_view/where?key=\"m0rph3v5\""];
```

I've also tried using %22 instead of the double quotes which didn't work either.

How can I succesfully add the double quotes in the request url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with the stringWithFormat I used which tried to decypher %22 as a variable as well and thus screwing up the url.

Using a nsmutablestring and appending the key variable turned out to be working properly :)

Answer (score 1):

Using %22 works for me. I get a valid NSURL object using this line of code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://username:password@gcg.cloudant.com:5984/points/_design/user/_view/where?key=%22m0rph3v5%22"];
```

The strange thing is that this works without escaping the @ sign. 
IIRC it should also be escaped (%40).

Comment: I indeed get a valid url object with that but the url results into the following: http://username:password@gcg.cloudant.com:5984/points/_design/user/_view/where?key=20rph3v52 , returning a bad request from couchdb itself since "m0rph3v5" ends up 20rph3v52